# Why Null Pointer Exception depends on order of condition?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am learning and experimenting with tutorials and I recently found a strange behavior. One of my if condition checks whether the reference variable is null or not and whether it's value matches the desired one or not but I am confused why it throws exception in second if block and not in first if block even though I have not added any extra condition and even the combination is also having 'and' clause. Any good article or pointer would be a great help.

My code:

```
class Dummy {
    int a;
    int b;
}

public class Doubt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str =  null;
        Dummy d = null;
        if(str!=null && str.equals("My Input")) {
            System.out.println("This doesn't throw exception");
        }
        System.out.println("last if didn't throw exception");
        try{
            if(str.equals("My Input") && str!=null ) {
                System.out.println("This throws exception");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please read about [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). Any decent book or class or tutorial should have a note about the logical operators `&&` and `||` and that they do it.

Answer (score 4):

Conditions are evaluated in the order they are written (if they need to be, i.e., haven't been short-circuited out, of course).

Consider evaluating the second `if` statement with `str=null`. You first attempt to check `str.equals("My Input")`, which will throw a `NullPointerException`, with the second condition never being reaching. On the other hand, in the first `if` statement, you first check `str != null`. Since this is `false` and `false && anything` will always return `false`, the following condition isn't even evaluated, and no `NullPointerException` is thrown. This is called short-circuit evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is thrown, because in an 'and' relation the first statement is checked first and then the second, and you first statement throws the exception because the string is null.
Because of this behaviour you should always write the null check first.

Answer (score 0):

The condition evaluation is from left to right.

```
if(str!=null && str.equals("My Input"))
```

In this case, `str!=null` would be evaluated first and if true, then only `str.equals("My Input")` would be evaluated.

```
if(str.equals("My Input") && str!=null )
```

In this case `str.equals("My Input")` would be evaluated first and when `str` is null, it would throw NPE.